# Gatling request with random number of body parts

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to test a HTTP upload API that accepts a list of files in a single request.
I want to write a Gatling script that generates a request with a random number of body parts each time.

This is what I have:

```
feed(feeder)
  .exec(
    {
      var req = http("My request")
        .post("/${id}")
        .header("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed")

      1 to Random.nextInt(10) foreach {
        i => {
          req = req.bodyPart(
            ByteArrayBodyPart("file-put", session => randomByteArray(10 * 1024 + Random.nextInt(10 * 1024 * 1024)))
              .contentType("application/pdf")
              .fileName(session => s"/$i-UPLOAD-TEST.pdf")
          )
        }
      }
      req
    }
  )

private def randomByteArray(size: Int): Array[Byte] = {
    val bytes = new Array[Byte](size)
    Random.nextBytes(bytes)
    bytes
}
```

With every request the file sizes and contents are randomized, so the `randomByteArray` works fine. But each time I get the same number of body parts. I assume it's because the request "template" is generated at the start of the simulation, so the `foreach` loop runs only once and configures the number of body parts for all the future requests.

How can I make the number of body parts random each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to build each branch (one for one part, one for 2, etc) beforehand and then [switch randomly](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/general/scenario.html#uniformrandomswitch).